# ko.mapping.fromJSON is not mapping into Model

Tags: knockout.js

I have MVC application that I am trying to convert information fetched from tables (Table1: Product, Table2: ProductTag) into JSON.

On my UI I wanted to map the JSON data into my model. For some reason there is no error but the UI is not displaying the mapped results. My get all products returns the json data but if failed to map it to the model Person.

console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); shows me that the Json file is returned from server call but some how it is not mapping it to my model. I have included the controller, the HTML and .js file for more information.

```
MVCController:

   public JsonResult GetAllProducts()
    {
        var products = Json(Repository.GetAll(), 
                 JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products,
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            });

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

   }

HTML:
 //script section -  shoppingcart.js

       <h2>ShoppingCart</h2>
   <div id="shoppingCart">
<h3>List of Products</h3>
<table id="products">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Tags</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach:Products">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="visible:false , text:Id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:Name">
            <td data-bind="text:Price"></td>
            <td>
                <ul data-bind="foreach:$root.ProductTags">
                    <li data-bind="text:$root.data"></li>
                </ul>
            <td><button data-bind="click: removeProduct">Remove</button> 
   </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
        shoppingcart.js:

           var ProductTag = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.Id = ko.observable();
        self.Fk_Product_Id = ko.observable();
        self.Name = ko.observable();
        }

        var Product = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.Id = ko.observable();
        self.Name = ko.observable();
        self.Price = ko.observable();
        self.ProductTags = ko.observableArray(); // array of Orders  

        self.removeProduct = function (order) {
            self.ProductTags.remove(order);
        }

        self.checkout = function () {
            alert("checkout...");
        };

        self.ProductTags = ko.observableArray();
        self.Product = ko.observable();
        self.Products = ko.observableArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ShoppingCart/GetAllProducts',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                var result = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
                var products = self.Products(result); //Put the response in ObservableArray
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                console.log(products);
            }
        });
    };

    $(function () {
        var viewModel = Product();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you might be double-serializing your data. Is `data` coming over as a string? What does it look like without calling JSON.stringify?

Comment: @JasonSpake
"{"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":null,"Data":[{"ProductTags":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Baked Goods","Fk_Product_Id":1},{"Id":2,"Name":"Hot Dogs","Fk_Product_Id":1}],"Id":1,"Name":"Buns","Price":1.00},{"ProductTags":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Baked Goods","Fk_Product_Id":1},{"Id":2,"Name":"Hot Dogs","Fk_Product_Id":1}],"Id":1,"Name":"Buns","Price":1.00},{"ProductTags":[{"Id":0,"Name":null,"Fk_Product_Id":3}],"Id":3,"Name":"test","Price":3.00}],"JsonRequestBehavior":0,"MaxJsonLength":null,"RecursionLimit":null}"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're probably double-serializing your data. In your controller you're using Newtonsoft's JsonConvert.SerializeObject which serializes your object to a json string, and then returning that as a JsonResult which I think then serializes it again using microsoft's default json serializer. Try removing one of those layers; either get rid of the JsonConvert or have the function return that result directly as a string.

```
public string GetAllProducts()
{
    var products = Json(Repository.GetAll(), 
             JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products,
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });

    return result;
}
```